# Help with finding equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the hyperbolic equation that satisfies: Foci:$(\pm3,0)$ and hyperbola passes through the point $(4,1)$.

I have tried to say $3^2=a^2+b^2$, so $b^2=9-a^2$ and I know that $$\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$ so that means that $$\frac{4^2}{a^2}-\frac{1^2}{9-a^2}=1$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the center is at $(0,0)$ (you didn't specify), you did it right. From the equation you get that $a=\pm 3\sqrt{2}$ or $a=\pm 2\sqrt2$ (it's much easier to solve for $a^2$, and more useful too, by the way). Plugging this back in, you see that $a=\pm 3\sqrt{2}$ wouldn't give you a real answer so your $a$ can only be $a=\pm 2\sqrt2$, and $a^2$ (which is really the only thing we care about) is $8$. From this we get that $b^2=1$ by plugging it back into the equation. Our final equation is therefore:
$$\therefore \frac{x^2}{8}-y^2=1$$

Comment: You're always here for us Shahar! Thanks!